# Android detect red color in a video if it exists

Tags: android, computer-vision

I am a total beginner in android development especially when it comes to detections so please help me. Basically what I want is that I need to detect if there is a red colour in a video. How would I do that? Can you please give some suggestions, some tutorials or sample code that would help me. I heard from my friend that I need to use computer vision. Is that necessary? Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, a picture contains 3 channels colors from a video stream. This 3 channels compose each 3 digitals primary colors RGB (red green blue). Generally, 3 matrix on android contains each channel values.
When you know that, you understand that the color appeared in red when the 3 composites are as (255, 0, 0) in case of image depth is 8bit. In other word, the red value is greater than 2 others.

You must test and determine a predicate.

To help you, I tell you to look OpenCV framework for Android... ^^

Comment: Hello thanks for answering! Would you mind if you would give me some tutorials? Or any sample coding?

Comment: I tell you :"search on your best friend..." It's easy to find android sample code. Good luck ^^